# Can't get a scatter plot to show values over time of a day

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset with a pulse for every minute over several days. I grouped it into several different pulse zones so I can set a color for an each serie. In google spreadsheets I can get the desired result in just 2 clicks - I select the time column and values, choose a scatter plot and that's all. However, I can't make the same thing in Power BI. I tried almost everything, read some guides, tried adding id column in details - nothing is working as I want to, says data incompatible, though its recognized as date hierarchy and time respectfully. Can't add more values to Y axis.

What do I need: to display every record as a dot, where X is the time of a day, and Y is the value

Example:
[image: needed result]

Data sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M6bgIwBflp0rp_w507f_l-D6FqBSuwknyQy2SvVXGdE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks like there is a lot of duplication in your data. The columns to the right of the Group column are not needed.

Power BI does not plot time values on a chart axis. You need to convert the time value to a number if you want to use it on the X axis of a scatter chart.

In the Power Query editor, convert the **Time** column from a data type of **Time* to a type of **Duration**.

Then you can pull the Time to the X axis and the hearRate to the Y axis. Pull the Group to the legend. I only plotted a small sample of your data.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thank you very much! But can I make it so that X axis shows the time in a normal way?

Comment: you could multiply the duration by 24. Then the numbers on the axis would be the 24 hours in a day. You won't be able to see a time value like 15:30, though. It would show as 15.5.